# A confusion on the current gain of an NPN transistor

Tags: current, npn, gain

[image]

In above screenshot V2 is increasing ramp voltage from 0 to 12V, which accordingly increases Ib. Transistor is an NPN type.

Ic(q1) is the collector current.

Vce = V1 is a constant 1V.

So it means Im keeping Vce constant and only increasing Ib.

Many tutorials say in amplification region Ib/Ic is constant and called beta i.e. hfe.

But the blue plot which is Ic/Ib is very different than what I expect.
What is wrong?

edit: Here is after I decreased the base current with  FakeMoustache's suggestions:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations, you just figured out why the \$h_{fe}\$ value is meaningless for most situations. Besides that the value varies greatly for a specific product. Have a look at the datasheet for the transistor you are using there and the different values and conditions where that value was measured.

Comment: Some remarks: using the "DC sweep" simulation is better suited for this kind of thing. Why force Vce at 1 V while driving the transistor "hard" ? Note that you get ridiculously high Ic currents. Your base resistor has a very low value, why ? In another question you said you use a PWM signal, you use a ramp here, why ?

Comment: But many tutorials take this as a fixed value

Comment: I think you're confusing small-signal AC analysis with this [large-signal] DC one.

Comment: Hfe can be assumed to have a fixed value UNDER CERTAIN CONDITIONS. Your conditions do not meet those. Your transistor is in saturation, then Hfe is much smaller.

Comment: Please forget about pwm. My question is only about hfe in amplification zone

Comment: OK, then the way you're using this transistor will only give you "nice" amplification in the region around t = 5 ms.

Comment: "But the blue plot which is Ic/Ib is very different than what I expect." What do you expect ???

Comment: I expect a contant horizontal line since Ic/Ib is constant according to tutorials. Btw even around 2ms the hfe is increasing with Ib. Note that Im keeping Vce constant.

Comment: For driving a transistor in saturation Hfe (note capital letter, denoting DC) is certainly expected to go down to "forced beta". See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204558/calculate-transistor-params-as-switch-to-operate-within-the-maximum-limits-safel/204581#204581 for another example.

Comment: That is because you're "mistreating" this NPN, you force a very large Ib but Vce is not enough to allow the IC that would need to flow when Hfe is large. Try with Ib as a current source from 1uA to 1mA and see what Ic does. Oh, use a DC-sweep this time, not a tran simulation ! See: http://denethor.wlu.ca/ltspice/#dsweep

Comment: @FakeMoustache Please see the edit in my question

Comment: Also link us to one of the many tutorials that say this is constant.

Comment: heres one: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-hfe-of-a-transistor  " The hFE is normally seen to be a constant value, normally around 10 to 500, but it may change slightly with temperature and with changes in collector-to-emitter voltage." In my case Vce is constant and the change of hfe is not slight.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it. In the mean time see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182962/is-the-current-gain-value-constant-for-a-single-bjt

Comment: You see that Hfe is now significantly larger ! Hfe is even more constant over a wider range and you can simulate that by using a current source for Ib in a DC sweep like I suggested. Try it, it is not hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over a substantial range of Ib (corresponding to V2=1.5 to 10V or Ib around 0.1 to 1.0 mA) you show that hFE for this transistor model varies only between 180 and 205. That is close enough to constant for many applications, especially in the context of all the other conditions that cause hFE to vary.

So some introductory texts may simplify their treatment of a transistor by pretending it is actually constant, in order to teach other things (aka small-signal analysis). A good text will return to this issue later on and explore the actual behaviour in more depth.

The [linked article](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-hfe-of-a-transistor) (from comments above) makes this statement without any such qualification. However it is on a [webpage](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/BJTs/) which also contains [this utter howler](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/PNP-transistors-normally-on-devices.php). In my estimation, such a page is actually worth LESS than you paid to read it!

Comment: I agree with Brian Drummon doubts. The article under discussion contains even more errors.

Comment: Actually, what I said in my previous comment (now deleted) was incorrect. In this case the degradation in beta is due to high-level injection which for this particular model kicks in early. Speaking of which... LTspice ships with a lot of dubious transistor models, but for this one its Gummel plot looks somewhat plausible.